# As a Christian can I marry a Muslim in an Islamic Nikah w/o first having 'secular' legal wedding?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam, ahlul-kitab, secular

I will try to be as short as possible in looking for an answer as I asked so many people but got no clear answer.

I’m a Christian and my fiancé is Muslim. We want to do the Islamic wedding. We are currently living in a Muslim country, but we don’t want to do it here. We want to have the Islamic wedding first, but we are not officially, legally married yet. Is it this possible, to have the blessing from an imam first ?

I’m from Romania, but we could travel anywhere to do it! We both know each other’s family’s (if that matters) and everyone is supporting our beautiful story. We have been together for 5 years, but only now we are 100% of this step.

**Which countries would give as this blessing without having the official papers ?**

Thank you so much everyone!

Edit:
The woman (me) I’m Christian , my fiancé (the man) is Muslim. 
No, in romania “Islam” is not our official religion therefore what I understood is that they do give a document but without any official value. 
I have moved out of my country for 6 years. My fiancé’s works for the army in the country we are now, and marriage with another nationality is not allowed. We have requested so many times, and we always been declined. Now, none of us wants to live like this forever, and we want to be legal in the eyes of God, and in our hearts, and we could make the civil documents, once he can find another job, or after 2 years when he could retire.
I know the story is long and complicated, I’m looking for answers to find the right step. And I need help from someone who can understand this complicated situation.

Comment: Answers can be in either Arabic or English. Waiting for an answer from an expert. Thank you !

Comment: Is the Christian person a male or female? Is the Muslim a male or female?

Comment: What country is it?

Comment: @Catalina In the countries I have lived, the Imam responsible for marriage is authorized to issue a marriage certificate/license. Hence, I don't quite understand your dilemma. Do Imams in Romania not give official marriage documents when one is married in the masjid? Or does the Romanian government not officially recognize such documentation?

Answer (score 1):

As said before in the comment for a valid marriage in Islam you need:

- two trustworthy -Muslim- witnesses.
- the bride needs a wali (guardian) usually her father who would give his agreement for the marriage in front of the witnesses. If he can't be present he may appoint another men as a legal substitute. Note in Islam Muslim women and women from among the people of book require a guardian.

Finally both the bride and groom must approave and accept marrying each other.

- Note that marriage is only valid in case of chastity, as Allah said:

  > ... And [lawful in marriage are] **chaste women** from among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given the Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret] lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers ([5:5](https://legacy.quran.com/5/5))

So in case of premarital intercourse one must first repent sincerly to God and stop this act, and ask for forgiveness to be counted as chaste. See also [Can we marry non-chaste women of the book al kitaab?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34962/can-we-marry-non-chaste-women-of-the-book-al-kitaab?s=3|43.5159). This means that one must leave the sin and the co-sinner and seek a legal way of living together a first step might be a legal engagement, this still doesn't allow any interaction that goes beyond a simple talk. Or seek a legal marriage. Note that many imam's who perform marriages in non-Muslim countries don't seem to care about this point (which is important if you want a legal marriage in front of Allah).

I can't tell you in which country you may get married via an Imam, but in most non-Muslim countries this seems usual (I do live in Germany) and in many Muslim countries too. Some Muslim countries rather require an official way (for example Morocco, nevertheless there are some exceptions -which are against the law), so getting the marriage papers may require time (usually 1-2 weeks).

But basically if you find an imam of a mosque that would write a 'Aqd an-Nikah (a marriage contract) for you which clearly testifies the presence of the witnesses and the acceptance of all necessary parties (Guardian/bride and groom) it should be sufficient. You may consider wearing something descent maybe even take a scarf as some imam's or mosque's may require this.

P.S.:

- Maybe you may consider reading up on whether such a contract would be accepted in either your Country or your grooms country. Note that you may seek a civil marriage later in any case.
- Based on my experience it is often rather useless to try to get an information by calling a mosque by phone unless it is a bigger Muslim Centre, the easiest and quickest way is often to simply go there at the prayer times and ask.